# How do you move tree with ignore patterns in python

Tags: python

with the shutil.copytree I can copy an entire directory with files and folders into a folder within itself and at the same time ignore certain folders and there content.

```
source = htpc.root
destination = os.path.join(htpc.root, "old")

shutil.copytree(source, destination, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('userdata', 'old'))
```

Is there a way to do this exact same thing except move and not copy so I'll only be left userdata and old in the root directory with all the old files and folders within old. Any assistance would be great. Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any existing way of doing this, but a hackish solution might be to wrap your ``shutil.ignore_patters()`` in something which records the files moved (by getting the difference between the input and output for the function) and then deleting those files - at that point, it might just be worth implementing your own ``movetree``, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shutil` module does not provide that function.

You can see the the `copytree()` function, and others, in the file: `shutil.py`.

Perhaps located at: `/usr/local/python2.6/shutil.py`

There are 9 functions, [shutil pydoc](http://pydoc.org/2.4.1/shutil.html).

Because copytree is so close to what you need already, I would approach this by cloning copytree() to a new function and then tweaking it to move rather than copy.

To do this:

Find `shutil.py` on your system and open in a text editor/IDE.

Find the line that says:

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
```

Copy everything from here to the end of the copytree function.

Then paste this into your code and rename to something like `def moveWithIgnore(src, ...` or `move2(..)`.

The comments at the top of the original copytree() function say copy2() does the 'work'. In `shutils.py` you can see it takes `(src, dst)` as arguments.

Also in shutils is the `move()` function, which also takes `(src, dst)`. It looks like it is safe to swap `copy2` for `move` in the new `moveWithIgnore` function.

The original `copytree()` function uses recursion (it calls itself). Be sure to update the line of code in the new function so it calls itself rather than copytree.

I'm sure you can take it from here :-)